# Pipenv successfully installed and created correct Pipfile, but dependencies not installed

Tags: shell, dependencies, virtualenv, pipenv

While creating a python package, i used `pipenv install flask flask-sqlalchemy` to create a pipfile. However, after I run `pipenv shell`, and `flask-sqlalchemy --version`, it says the package does not exits. `zsh: command not found: flask-sqlalchemy`

The pipfile generated correctly:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask = "*"
flask-sqlalchemy = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
```

But the packages do not seemed to be accessible.

Additional information:
Mac Python 3.10.11 pip 23.1.2
*commands used in virtual environment.

```
`where python3`
/Users/user_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/twitoff_CMR-WZ6L3rrF/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

`where flask-sqlalchemy`
flask-sqlalchemy not found

`where flask`
/Users/user_name/.local/share/virtualenvs/twitoff_CMR-WZ6L3rrF/bin/flask
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/flask

I have tried uninstalling, reinstalling, and upgrading pipenv.
... upgrading pip then upgrading pipenv.
... closing and opening the terminal every change.
... changing version of python

In the virtual environment, I expect the name and version number when flask-sqlalchemy --version.

Comment: "*I expect the name and version number when flask-sqlalchemy --version.*" Why? `flask-sqlalchemy` is not a program to run in command line, it's a Python package to be imported. It's a plugin for `flask`.

Comment: You are correct. Also, I found that using pip list will show all libraries in the virtual environment.